# Android, RecyclerView, TableRow, 1 column with a non-Breaking line and 2 equal columns

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to match the 1 column width to the maximum length of the text in that column.

[Column too short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFGZm.jpg)

[Column too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDygS.jpg)

[Fine column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB99g.jpg)

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/id"
      android:layout_width="50dp"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/term"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/definition"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

https://github.com/softfly/RecyclerListApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/item.xml

I had the idea to compute to and set a fixed value. But every android has a different display, and that doesn't work very well.

```
private int calcIdTextViewWidth() {
    return Integer.toString(
            items.stream()
                    .mapToInt(Item::getId)
                    .max()
                    .orElse(0)
    ).length() * 30 + 70;
}
```

https://github.com/softfly/RecyclerListApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/recyclerlist/ExampleRecyclerViewAdapter.java

I have 1 idea.

1. Set android:layout_width="wrap_content" for the 1 column.
2. Find the max width.
3. Refresh the view with fixed width, but how to refresh all rows with a new width?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well what I have in mind is probably way too convoluted, but if you want to calculate the length of your `TextView`, you can do so at runtime.

This cannot be done in `onCreate`, as there the sizes of the Views have not yet been calculated, you will have to add a Listener to react to measure it afterwards.

What I would suggest in most usecase where you have to measure something after creation is using a `GlobalLayoutListener`.

In your Activity's `onCreate` Method add:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
    int text_width = textView.getWidth();
});
```

This Method will be called everytime your layout changes (e.g. when the phone rotates) so also when the layout is created.
You can do all your calculations of on-sceen elements there.